# Constraints menu is not showing, why? (Xcode 5)

Tags: ios, xcode, constraints, autolayout

I had just finished my app and I was about to add constraints to it to make it fit both 4th and 5th generation screens, but I noticed that the constraints menu was not showing. My question is why? How can I make it appear?

This is how it looks: http://i.gyazo.com/0bd5bef937767162010c040d59945871.png

And I can't make it appear: http://i.gyazo.com/4289fe479dfbc3da44fb093f2a23e42e.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you enable "Use Auto Layout"?

[image]

Comment: No, I had missed that. Thank you very much! @tyt_g207

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you enable Use Auto Layout.  Also, the constraints menu might not appear if nothing is selected.